# How do I get a list of directories from a network folder using c#?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to get a list of folders (and then files) from a network drive in C#, but when I try to run `Directory.GetDirectories(@"\\10.188.169.139\builds\product A")` I get the error:

> System.IO.IOException -  Message: "The
> network path was not found.\r\n"

If I open a file explorer and paste in the path `\\10.188.169.139\builds\product A` it opens that folder. I'm running Visual Studio as an Administrator.

What could I be missing?

Comment: Have you tried escaping the backslash characters? So in your case, your c# string would be: `@"\\\\10.188.169.139\\builds\\product A"`

Comment: I think there's something going on there. When I try this in my network and use the IP adress like you did, I get UnauthorizedAccessException, but when I use the host name instead of the IP adress, it works as expected. Though in my case it's a Samba share hosted on a linux machine.

Comment: @WSC Same error when I double the backslashes.

Comment: @alsed42 That would be a problem since there is no hostname. This is just network addressable storage so no host.

Comment: I'm not sure how (I would excpect an other exception) but it probably has to do with running VS as administrator. Can you qccess this unc path from the open file dialog of VS?

Comment: You could try mapping it to a drive letter then.

Comment: @kd345205 How would Path.Combine help here?

Comment: @alsed42 I tried that. Same result

Comment: @Steeeve Oddly no - I can't. When I do File->Open File and then paste that path (or the mapped version (z:\builds\Product A)) it won't resolve.

Comment: Then try a net use ... in an elevated command prompt if you need to run VS as admin. Afterwards it should also work from your project.

Comment: @Steeeve How is net use different from mapping a drive? I've tried a mapped drive and I'm running VS as an admin. I'm starting to think I'm going to need to just copy the folders I need to read locally to this machine using another process and then just access them locally.

Comment: The difference is, if you map a drive in explorer, you can't do it for the administrator because you can't start explorer as administrator. Elevated processes do not have the same network connections as non-elevated processes. That's why you will need a `net use ...` in an elevated command prompt. You can also execute `net show` in an elevated and a non-elevated command prompt to see the differences. But if your app will not run as admin, it should work properly if you are starting it without VS, which in your case is running as admin (therefore your prog also).

Comment: There is a [workaround](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-client/networking/mapped-drives-not-available-from-elevated-command) to have the same network connections in elevated processes, but I don't recommend it. If you need the network connections often from VS running as admin, I would suggest to create a batchfile with the needed net use comands and execute is als admin to get the connections on behalf.

Comment: Make sure the user you're running your app as has permission to access the network location you're attempting to access.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an answer per-se, but this is how I got around the issue. I created a build step that copies builds to a share on the machine I'm using for automated testing as the last build step. That way I don't need to access a network share.